# SQL - Splitting string in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split, sql-server-2019

I'd like to split the result from a query and display the values in separate columns. As an example I get the following result

```
|Name          |
|ABC_DEFG_HIJKL|
|A_B_C         |
|A_B_C_D       |
```

I want to split the values by '_' and add them to separate columns.
The query result should look something like this

```
|Name          |first   |second   |third   |fourth|
|ABC_DEFG_HIJKL|ABC     |DEFG     |HIJKL   |null  |
|A_B_C         |A       |B        |C       |null  |
|A_B_C_D       |A       |B        |C       |D     |
```

So far I can split the result. But for each value, I have a new row. So I just need to merge the results into one row and make a column for each of those rows.

```
SELECT DP.Name, value  
FROM RitopDatenpunkt DP  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(DP.Name, '_'); 


|Name          |value   |
|ABC_DEFG_HIJKL|ABC     |
|ABC_DEFG_HIJKL|DEFG    |
|ABC_DEFG_HIJKL|HIJKL   |
|A_B_C         |A       |
|A_B_C         |B       |
|A_B_C         |C       |
|A_B_C_D       |A       |
|A_B_C_D       |B       |
|A_B_C_D       |C       |
|A_B_C_D       |D       |
```

I know that I should use PIVOT. But what aggragate function do I use and are the arguments for the FOR statement right

```
SELECT DP.Name, value  
FROM RitopDatenpunkt DP  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(DP.Name, '_')
PIVOT
(
        GROUPING(Name) as Name
        FOR value in ([first],[second],[third],[fourth])
)piv;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using JSON functions:

```
select t.name,
    json_value(x.obj, '$[0]') name1,
    json_value(x.obj, '$[1]') name2,
    json_value(x.obj, '$[2]') name2,
    json_value(x.obj, '$[3]') name4
from mytable t
cross apply (values('["' + replace(t.name, '_', '", "') + '"]')) x(obj)
```

The trick is to manipulate the string to make it look like a JSON array (that' what the `cross apply` subquery does). Basically this turns a string like `'A_B_C'` to `'["A", "B", "C"]'`. We can then use `json_value()` to easily access each individual element.

This does not assume anything about the elements being unique. Actually the only requirement is that the string should not contain embedded double quotes.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4bfc0d78694f904c7934d954da906357)**:

```
name           | name1 | name2 | name2 | name4
:------------- | :---- | :---- | :---- | :----
ABC_DEFG_HIJKL | ABC   | DEFG  | HIJKL | null 
A_B_C          | A     | B     | C     | null 
A_B_C_D        | A     | B     | C     | D
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no duplicates in the string, you can use this rather cumbersome method:

```
SELECT dp.*, s.*
FROM RitopDatenpunkt DP CROSS APPY 
     (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 1 THEN s.value END) as first,
             MAX(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 2 THEN s.value END) as second,
             MAX(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 3 THEN s.value END) as third,
             MAX(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 4 THEN s.value END) as fourth
      FROM (SELECT s.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX('_' + s.value + '_', '_' + DP.Name + '_')) as seqnum
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(DP.Name, '_') s
           ) s
     ) s;
```

This uses `CHARINDEX()` to find the values in the original string and then uses conditional aggregation to create the columns in order.

Unfortunately, `STRING_SPLIT()` does *not* guarantee the ordering.  An alternative approach is to use a recursive CTE or to mis-use the [`PARSENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, if you don't have more than four components.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PARSENAME()` too as:

```
SELECT Val,
       PARSENAME(Value, 1) Name1,
       PARSENAME(Value, 2) Name2,
       PARSENAME(Value, 3) Name3,
       PARSENAME(Value, 4) Name4
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('ABC_DEFG_HIJKL'), 
  ('A_B_C'),
  ('A_B_C_D')
) T(Val) CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(Val, '_', '.'))) TT(Value);
```

Note that this won't work if you have more than 3 `'_'`.